# How to create a function in oracle in which i don't know the count of input parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to create a function which calculates non-zero avg of columns (in a row). But i don't know how to have columns passed as parameter to that function since i don't know the count of parameters, which can vary from 1 to 50.

Like greatest/least function.

Comment: Are you looking for [AVG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions018.htm#i82074) function?

Comment: no. its more like least/greatest function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 option

The first one
You need 2 parameters: 
1. table name for your avg calculation
2. either xmltype or varchar2 or clob which contains the list of fields
3. id of the row in your table

Next step you create dynamic sql which extracts and inserts values from the table sequentialy either in a temporary table or a collection and calculates ordinal AVG.

The second one:
Just one parameter - table of number (collection I meant) which you populate by yourself and calculate avg on it.

If you like a stupid solution create 50 overloaded functions with number of parameters from 1 to 50 in a package.